# how to break the string using keywords using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a scenario where i need to break the below input string based on the keywords using regex.

Keywords are UPRCAS, REPLC, LOWCAS and TUPIL.

```
String input = "UPRCAS-0004-abcdREPLC-0003-123TUPIL-0005-adf2344LOWCAS-0003-ABCD";
```

The output should be as follows

```
UPRCAS-00040-abcd
REPLC-0003-123
TUPIL-0005-adf2344
LOWCAS-00030-ABCD
```

How can i achieve this using java regex.

I have tried using split by '-' and using regex but both the approach gives an array of strings and again i have to process each string and combine 3 strings together to form `UPRCAS-00040-abcd`. I felt this is not the efficient way to do as it takes an extra array and process them back.

```
String[] tokens = input.split("-");
String[] r = input.split("(?=\\p{Upper})");
```

Please let me know if we can split the string using regex based on the keyword. Basically i need to extract the string between the keyword boundary.

***Edited question after understanding the limitation of existing problem***

---

- The regex should be generic to extract the string from input between the UPPERCASE characters
- The regex should not contains keywords to split the string.

I understood that, it is a bad idea to add new keyword everytime in regex pattern for searching. My expectation is to be a generic as possible.

Thanks all for your time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: *Comment to edited question:* If you split on UPPERCASE characters, your 4th value would be split to `LOWCAS-00030-` and `ABCD`. Unless you can *guarantee* that all values expect the last one will *never* use uppercase characters except in the prefix, using UPPERCASE will not work.

Comment: Yes. In that case I need to compare the keyword with each extraction of output string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
\w+-\w+-(?:[a-z0-9]+|[A-Z]+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/etKBjI/3

Comment: Question explicitly say *"Keywords are UPRCAS, REPLC, LOWCAS and TUPIL"*, but your regex ignores that and tries to infer logic by case sensitivity, however that only works for the given example because the first 3 values don't have uppercase in the third part. This regex will fail badly if you simply change the order of the 4 values. If the requirement is to look for 4 keywords, then not looking for the keywords will not be valid for all possible inputs.

Comment: @MYGz thanks for the 2 cents. I found this solution quite interesting because this helps me to split the input into group of strings without specifying the keyword. Infact I will redesign the code based on this regex. I realized that, suppose tomorrow I added 100 keywords I should not change the expression each time. The code should be scalable. I will edit the question.

Comment: Thanks @Andeas for pointing out the flaws. I came in a jiffy and ignored everything except the input and output since it was a java question and I am Python dev. Would have deleted this on your comment but since OP can see a different perspective, i'll leave it.

Comment: @MadhuCM Don't edit this question. Accept Andreas's solution and ask a separate question.

Comment: @MadhuCM If the values had been listed in reverse order (`LOWCAS-00030-ABCDTUPIL-0005-adf2344REPLC-0003-123UPRCAS-00040-abcd`), how would you know where to split `ABCDTUPIL` without explicitly listing `TUPIL` as a keyword? Beware building logic on a single *example*. Consider all possible inputs.

Comment: @MadhuCM Please revert the question back to original and accept Andreas's solution. My solution would fail for the reasons Andreas mentioned in his 1st comment.

Comment: @MYGz you are right I thought about that case if uppercase are prefixed with keyword. and thanks for pointing it out. will try to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Split using the following regex:

```
(?=UPRCAS|REPLC|LOWCAS|TUPIL)
```

The `(?=xxx)` is a [zero-width positive lookahead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special), meaning that it matches the empty space immediately preceding one of the 4 keywords.

See [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for more information: [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

*Test*

```
String input = "UPRCAS-0004-abcdREPLC-0003-123TUPIL-0005-adf2344LOWCAS-0003-ABCD";
String[] output = input.split("(?=UPRCAS|REPLC|LOWCAS|TUPIL)");
for (String value : output)
    System.out.println(value);
```

*Output*

```
UPRCAS-0004-abcd
REPLC-0003-123
TUPIL-0005-adf2344
LOWCAS-0003-ABCD
```